# change json key name dynamic

Tags: php, json

i have generated a json according to my sql query out put here is my json output, i have listed few of my json code

```
  "42":"",
  "field_id_25":"",
  "43":null,
  "field_ft_25":null,
  "44":"",
  "field_id_26":"",
  "45":null,
  "field_ft_26":null,
  "46":"",
  "field_id_27":"",
  "47":null,
  "field_ft_27":null,
```

i have to change json key **field_ft_$$** according to my database table values..

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|      field id       |     field name   |
|---------------------|------------------|
|     field_id_27     | meta_description |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

ive coded in php then after i dont know how to finish..

```
<?php

  $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","penn");
  if (!$con) {
    echo "Failed";
  }


  // Retrive Data From WebLog Title
  $sql="SELECT * FROM `exp_weblog_titles` LEFT JOIN `exp_weblog_data` ON `exp_weblog_data`.`entry_id` = `exp_weblog_titles`.`entry_id` WHERE exp_weblog_titles.weblog_id='13' LIMIT 2 ";
  $query=mysqli_query($con,$sql);

  while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)) 
  {
    $data[] = $row;
  }


    // Convert The Weblog title data to json
    $json_string = json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    echo $json_string;


  // Retrive web_log_field_List as a array from database
  $sql1="SELECT field_id,field_name FROM exp_weblog_fields";
  $query1=mysqli_query($con,$sql1);

  while ($row1=mysqli_fetch_array($query1))   {
     $web_log_field[$row1['field_id']] = $row1['field_name'];
  }  
  // echo $web_log_field[21];


?>
```

example - i need to change "field_ft_27":null to "meta_description": null and others according to my database values

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. You want to change `"field_ft_27":null` to `"meta_description": null`?

Comment: i need to change "field_ft_27":null to "meta_description": null

Answer (score 1):

Use a regular expression to extract the appropriate parts of `field_ft_XX` and get the corresponding `field_id_XX` element of `$web_log_field`. Then you can delete the old key and add the replacement key.

```
foreach ($data as &$row) {
    foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
        if (preg_match('/^field_ft_(\d+)$/', $key)) {
            $idkey = "field_id_$key[1]";
            if (isset($web_log_field[$idkey])) {
                $row[$web_log_field[$idkey]] = $value;
                unset($row[$key]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```